# MongoDB push in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an document like the example below and need to create a script to insert a key F in the array configs if does not exists.

```
{
    "_id" : "5cde9ea5e326cd4bebbb2251",
    "scenario" : "SCENARIO_A",
    "step" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "STEP_TYPE_A",
            "configs" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : "A"
                }, 
                {
                    "key" : "B"
                }, 
                {
                    "key" : "C"
                }, 
                {
                    "key" : "D"
                }, 
                {
                    "key" : "E"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I create this code but it is not working, it is not insert the item in the array.

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('MyColletion').find({
  "scenario": "SCENARIO_A",
  "step.type": "STEP_TYPE_A",
  "step.configs.key": "F"
});

if (!cursor.hasNext()) {
    cursor = db.getCollection('MyColletion').find({"scenario": "SCENARIO_A", "step.type": "STEP_TYPE_A"});
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        var doc = cursor.next();
        print("updating doc with id = " + doc._id);
        db.collection.update(
            { "_id" : doc._id, "step.type": "STEP_TYPE_A" },
            { "$push": 
                { "step.$.configs": 
                    {
                        "key" : "F"
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        print("step does not exist");
    }
} else {
    print("config does not exist");
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Might want to try this? `{"_id": ObjectId(doc._id),  "step.type": "STEP_TYPE_A" , ...}`?

Comment: Tried this idea but still not updating. The console show the messages: updating doc with id = 5cde9ea5e326cd4bebbb2251 and Updated 0 record(s) in 1ms

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the line:

```
db.collection.update(
```

I changed to:

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').update(
```